# Error: Invalid glob argument for an src path, works as variable

Tags: gulp

Trying to set up gulp to concat some CSS files.

In my `gulpfile.js` I have this:

```
const paths = {
  css: {
    cssForConcat: [
      './css/*.css',
      '!./css/style.css',
    ],
  }
}
```

But this code:

```
function styles () {
  return gulp.src([paths.css.cssForConcat])
```

Returns an error:

```
[07:23:27] 'styles' errored after 811 μs
[07:23:27] Error: Invalid glob argument: ./css/*.css,!./css/style.css
```

Copying-and-pasting the constant value works OK with no error:

```
function styles () {
  return gulp.src('./css/*.css', '!./css/style.css')
```

What is wrong with my constant definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you passed in `[['./css/*.css', '!./css/style.css']]` rather than `'./css/*.css', '!./css/style.css'`, just remove the brackets around `paths.css.cssForConcat` and it should work as expected.

E.g.: `return gulp.src(paths.css.cssForConcat)`